# modal not open in google chrome but still open in firefox

Tags: bootstrap-modal

Modal is not load in Google Chrome but yes it is open in Mozilla Firefox.

-> bootstrap and jQuery js is replaced done.

-> also check conflict of js.

-> also i have re implement my whole code step by step.

But still problem is not resolved.

In console below error is shown:

[image]

Comment: show us ur code!!!

Answer (score 0):

below is the code sequence of added script file and CSS file.

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title><?php echo $site_name; ?></title>
    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="assests/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/Main.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/Fr.star.css" />
    <link href="assests/css/common.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/css/datepicker.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/js_player/simpleplayer.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/kashyap/css/fileinput.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/kashyap/css/custom-style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assests/kashyap/css/media-query.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assests/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assests/js/bootstrap-datepicker.js"></script>
    <script src="assests/js/jquery.validate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="assests/kashyap/js/fileinput.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/jquery.form.js"></script>
    <script src="assests/js_player/audiojs/audio.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assests/js/jquery.creditCardValidator.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have use onclick function on select option.